# Partitioning convex polygons into quadrilaterals of equal area and perimeter

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

This post records a little bit more on this question:  [Partitioning convex polygons into triangles of equal area and perimeter](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428243/partitioning-convex-polygons-into-triangles-of-equal-area-and-perimeter).

The basic question of the above linked post was about this claim: ""For any convex polygon, there is some finite value of a positive integer n such that the polygon allows partition into n triangles all of which are of same area." The claim may not be true (please see above post).

**Question:** What happens if we replace 'triangles' in above claim with 'convex quadrilaterals'? The new claim thus generated appears more likely to be true.

**Note:** In the new claim, one can replace "area" with "perimeter" or diameter or combinations such as "area and perimeter", " area and diameter",... and generate further questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convex quadrilateral decompositions of equal area are always possible. Given a convex polygon $P$ with at least $5$ sides, draw a line from one of the vertices of $P$ to a point $Q$ on one of the edges furthest from $P$ (in the graph sense). As we vary the location of $Q$ continuously, we'll find some decomposition into two convex pieces with strictly fewer sides whose areas are in a rational ratio.

Repeating as necessary, we obtain a collection of quadrilaterals whose areas are rational multiples of one another; from there, we just need to subdivide the quadrilaterals into smaller pieces the size of their least common divisor $d$, which we can do by cutting off quadrilateral-shaped chunks of area $d$ from each piece by connecting two points on opposite sides. (As we slide the two points freely, we can obtain any fraction of the area between $0$ and $1$.)

This only leaves the case where we start with a triangle, which is easy: since decompositions are affinely equivalent, we can assume our triangle is equilateral and draw three line segments from the center to the midpoints of the side to obtain our decomposition.

Comment: Nice answer to the area case of the question. Thanks! The other cases where the quadrilateral pieces have equal perimeter, etc. still remain. Hope they too generate elegant answers.