# Partitioning convex n-gons into least number of equal area convex quadrilaterals

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

This post adds a bit to [Partitioning convex polygons into quadrilaterals of equal area and perimeter](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428530/partitioning-convex-polygons-into-quadrilaterals-of-equal-area-and-perimeter)

**Question:** How does one achieve the partition of any given convex n-gon into the *least number* of equal area convex quadrilaterals? Note: The answer in above linked discussion shows that any convex n-gon can be cut into some finite number of convex quads.

**Further question:** Can any general (non-convex) n-gon be cut into some finite number of equal area quadrilaterals which are not necessarily convex? If so, how does one achieve the least number of such quads?

**Note:** Equal perimeter versions of these questions can also be asked.